# @Id annotation in JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

If I don't want to automatically generate the primary Key, instead, I want to supply the ID with the first column of the table as primary key.

```
2 A
4 B
7 D
13 E
```

...

I want the first column 2,4, 7, 13 to be the primary key of the table. Should I just use @Id to do the annotation?

```
@Entity
public class Code {
   @Id
   @Column(unique=true)
   private int id;

   ...
}
```

Or, if @Id is used, the primary key will be always automatically generated, instead of using the first column, in this case?

Comment: You don't need `unique=true`, if you use `@Id`.

Answer (score 4):

`@Id` will only declare the primary key. it will not insert generated value. if you use `@GeneratedValue` then it will generate the value of the field.

Comment: Should the primary key normally be automatically generated?

Comment: no ,, because in a table there can be non auto generated primary key also

Comment: Will JPA use @Id to perform update operations using the save() method?

Answer (score 0):

An `object id (OID)` is something that uniquely identifies an `object`. Within a `VM` this is typically the `object's` pointer. In a relational `database` `table`, a row is uniquely identified in its table by its `primary key`.

When persisting `objects` to a database you need a unique identifier for the `objects`, this allows you to query the `object`, define `relationships` to the `object`, and update and delete the `object`. In `JPA` the object id is defined through the `@Id` annotation and should correspond to the `primary key` of the `object's` table.

An `object id` can either be a natural id or a generated id. A natural id is one that occurs in the `object` and has some meaning in the application. Examples of natural ids include email addresses, phone numbers, and social insurance numbers. A generated id (also known as a surrogate id) is one that is generated by the system.

In `JPA` an `@Id` can be easily assigned a generated sequence number through the `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you always manually provide the primary key value for your entities, then the `@Id` annotation is enough.