# How to set an @Id primary key that is NOT Auto-Generated in Java JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Postgres with Java JPA/Hibernate and want to have the id field as one that is MANUALLY GENERATED by me. i.e. whenever i create an instance of this object, i set the id field anyway.

I've tried for weeks but keep running into either: "Required identifier property not found for class" or "After saving, the identifier must not be null".

Here is a sample of the model class i am using:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pojo")
public class Pojo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_one")
    private int idOne;

    @Column(name = "bool_example")
    private boolean boolExample;

    public Pojo(){};

    public Pojo(int idOne, boolean boolExample){
        this.idOne = idOne;
        this.boolExample = boolExample;
    }

    public int getIdOne() {
        return idOne;
    }

    public void setIdOne(int idOne) {
        this.idOne = idOne;
    }

    public boolean isBoolExample() {
        return boolExample;
    }

    public void setBoolExample(boolean boolExample) {
        this.boolExample = boolExample;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample request i'm calling in

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/plswork")
    public String pojotestone(){
        Pojo newpojo = new Pojo(1, false);
        pojoService.saveThis(newpojo);

        pojoService.test();
        return "yes";
    }
```

> The pojoService calls on pojoRepository.save(T entity). This pojoRepository is from extending CrudRepository so it creates queries on the fly

Comment: Check this answer to get some insight about the `@Id` -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275309/id-annotation-in-jpa-and-hibernate. It won't generate your PKs for you, but just the column.

Comment: Try `Integer` instead of `int`. Also override `equals` and `hashcode`. And make sure you have defined primary key in schema level.

Comment: The mapping looks good. What is the codes for  that `pojoService.saveThis(newpojo);` ?

Comment: @madhusdhnn i tried everything you've said, and still get "after saving identifier must not be null".

Comment: @KenChan its just calling save from the pojoRepository that extends Spring's CrudRepository.

Comment: I assume you have defined your `PojoRepository` like `interface PojoRepository extends CrudRepository<Pojo, Integer>`, correct?

Comment: @madhusdhnn yes, exactly.

Comment: May I know why do you manually generate ID?

Comment: *Here is a sample of the model class i am using:*. So is this the actual class you are using. If not, then post that.

Comment: What is the use case for maintaining the IDs manually. This is ridiculous and will only lead to problems.

Comment: Why not? It makes a lot of sense to have a manual id in business use cases. Credit Card class could have credit card no as primary key, user could have username/id as primary key. The use case is valid.

Comment: This should work fine as-is. Make sure that you're importing `@Id` from `javax.persistence.Id` and that you're not setting the ID to `null` somewhere in your code. Since this should work, I'm voting to close this as off-topic, as the details necessary to reproduce the problem are missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all those wondering,

YES - It is possible to have a manual id, and this makes sense in multiple use cases where entities have inherent id attributes. (such as credit cards, bank accounts, etc)

As for this problem, it turned out to be an incompatibility with Spring JDBC. The solution is to use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa instead, and **have repositories extend JPARepository instead of CrudRepository.**

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do that both in Spring Data JDBC(https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/2.2.12/reference/html/#is-new-state-detection) and Spring Data JPA(https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.7.7/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites.strategies). The most straightforward is implementing `Persistable<YourIdType` interface:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pojo")
public class Pojo implements Persistable<Integer>{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_one")
    private int idOne;

    @Column(name = "bool_example")
    private boolean boolExample;

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew;

    public setIsNew(boolean isNew) {
       this.isNew = isNew;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
      return isNew; 
    }

    //getters/setters/constructors...

}
```

now if you want to save a new entity with a id set in Java, you just need to call

```
pojo.setNew(true);
repository.save(pojo);
```